# Could not able to do bidirectional multicast connection using UDP

Tags: c, networking, udp, multicast

Have to make it server & client as bidirectional where I should able to send & receive data in console.

I can able to send data from server to client but not able to receive any data from client.Stuck in this for long time could not know how to resolve it.

I just started working on networking any lead on this really helpful.

Here is my code.

Server.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct in_addr localInterface;
struct sockaddr_in groupSock, rcv_addr;
int sd;
char databuf[1024];
int datalen = sizeof(databuf);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /* Create a datagram socket on which to send. */
    socklen_t rcv_addr_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sd < 0)
    {
        perror("Opening datagram socket error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Opening the datagram socket...OK.\n");

    memset((char*) &groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));
    groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("226.1.1.1");
    groupSock.sin_port = htons(4321);
    localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if (setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char*) &localInterface,
            sizeof(localInterface)) < 0) {

        perror("Setting local interface error");
        exit(1);
    } else
        printf("Setting the local interface...OK\n");
    int read_size;
    while (1) {
        memset(databuf, 0x00, sizeof(databuf));
        scanf("%s", databuf);
        datalen = strlen(databuf) + 1;
        if (sendto(sd, databuf, datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &groupSock,
                sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)

            datalen = 1024;
        memset(databuf, 0x00, sizeof(databuf));
        read_size = recvfrom(sd, databuf, datalen, 0,
                (struct sockaddr*) &rcv_addr, &rcv_addr_size);
        printf("The message from multicast ckient is: \"%s\"\n", databuf);

    }
    return 0;

}
```

client.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct sockaddr_in localSock, rcv_addr;
struct ip_mreq group;
int sd;
int datalen;
char databuf[1024];
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* Create a datagram socket on which to receive. */
    socklen_t rcv_addr_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sd < 0) {
        perror("Opening datagram socket error");
        exit(1);
    }

    else

        printf("Opening datagram socket....OK.\n");

    {
        int reuse = 1;
        if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*) &reuse,
                sizeof(reuse)) < 0) {
            perror("Setting SO_REUSEADDR error");
            close(sd);
            exit(1);
        } else
            printf("Setting SO_REUSEADDR...OK.\n");
    }
    memset((char*) &localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));
    localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localSock.sin_port = htons(4321);
    localSock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*) &localSock, sizeof(localSock))) {
        perror("Binding datagram socket error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    } else
        printf("Binding datagram socket...OK.\n");
    group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("226.1.1.1");
    group.imr_interface.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*) &group,
            sizeof(group)) < 0) {
        perror("Adding multicast group error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    } else
        printf("Adding multicast group...OK.\n");
    int read_size;
    while (1) {
        datalen = 1024;
        memset(databuf, 0x00, sizeof(databuf));
        read_size = recvfrom(sd, databuf, datalen, 0,
                (struct sockaddr*) &rcv_addr, &rcv_addr_size);
        printf("The message from multicast server is: \"%s\"\n", databuf);

        memset(databuf, 0x00, sizeof(databuf));
        scanf("%s", databuf);
        datalen = strlen(databuf) + 1;
        if (sendto(sd, databuf, datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &localSock,
                sizeof(localSock)) < 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation and remove the unnecessary empty lines

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add more details about your problem. What exactly means "*not able to receive any data from client*"? What do you do? What input do you use? What happens or what result do you get? Any error messages or error codes? What would you expect (and why)? You should try to simplify your program as far as possible to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is sending to the wrong address.

The server is using `localSock` as the destination address for `sendto`:

```
if(sendto(sd, databuf, datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock)) < 0)
```

But you have that address set to 0:

```
localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
localSock.sin_port = htons(4321);
localSock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

You want to instead use `rcv_addr`, which was populated as the source address from `recvfrom`.  Using this address as the destination will send the response back where it came from:

```
if(sendto(sd, databuf, datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&rcv_addr, sizeof(rcv_addr)) < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multicast connection is like broadcast communication, you send the packet to a forum of receivers, awaiting to read it, and they consume it (if it arrives).  This normally means that you have to arrange for bidirectional connection in a way that allows all people skeaking in a room and selecting yourself the responses, as everybody is talking to everybody in a multicast channel.  Imagine you are chatting in a IRC channel, and you have to arrange with somebody how to direct messages only to that person, but with the anarchy of anybody being able to respond to such messages in the way they want.  You have always to think that what you say, you say to everybody susbscribed in that multicast channel, so normally you will receive several response packets, from which you will have to select...